# A Conjecture related to minimization of product of determinants over permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, oc.optimization-and-control

Hi

I have the following problem (and a conjecture which holds in Matlab).
Given an $N\times N$ matrix $H$, represent it by its $2N\times 2N$ real-valued representation (which I will also denote by $H$ as the complex $H$ will not be used any further)
$$H = \left[\begin{array}{cc} \mathcal{R}(H)& -\mathcal{I}(H) \newline \mathcal{I}(H)& \mathcal{R}(H)\end{array}\right].$$
$N$ is always an even number.

I will now denote the first $N$ columns of $H$ by $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ and the last $N$ columns by $y_1,\ldots,y_N$. 
Now define the matrix
$$C=I-H^{\mathrm{T}}(HH^{\mathrm{T}} + \alpha I)^{-1}H,$$ for some $\alpha>0$.
By assumption, all values in $C$ are non-zero.

I am now interested in grouping the columns of $H$ 2-by-2 (Later I will generalize to M-by-M if the conjecture is correct) in some order so that I get $N$ pairs of columns. For example, with $N=4$ one such pairing would be 
$$(x_1,x_3),(x_2,y_1),(y_4,x_4),(y_2,y_3)$$
so I am allowed to group "one x with one y" but also "one x with another x" etc.
To each such pairing there is a corresponding permutation of the columns $\sigma$. I will write this $\sigma$ as
$$\sigma = \{v_{11}\,v_{12},v_{21}\,v_{22},\ldots,v_{N1}\,v_{N2}\}$$
to better visualize the pairs within the permutation.

Define the $2\times 2$ sub matrix of $C$
$$C_k = \left[\begin{array}{cc} C_{v_{k1}v_{k1}} & C_{v_{k1}v_{k2}} \newline C_{v_{k2}v_{k1}} & C_{v_{k2}v_{k2}}\end{array}\right].$$
Now, the cost function is
$$f(\sigma) = \prod_{k=1}^N \det(C_k)$$
and I would like to minimize this over $\sigma$.

Conjecture: (i) The optimal $\sigma$ is such that if I pair $x_i$ with $x_j$, then I will also pair $y_i$ with $y_j$. (ii) If I pair $x_i$ with $y_j$, then I will also pair $y_i$ with $x_j$. (iii) I will never pair $x_i$ with $y_i$.

The assumption of all elements in $C$ being non-zero is important for (iii).

Is this true....?